# How to gradually change lowpass frequency in webaudio?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm trying to gradually change the frequency amount of my lowpass filter, but instead of happening gradually, it happens instantly.

This code should start at a frequency, exponentially decrease to 200 at 1 second in, then stop at 2 seconds in. Instead it stays the same until 1 second where it instantly jumps to the lower frequency.

```js
var context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var oscillator = context.createOscillator();
var now = context.currentTime;


//lowpass node
var lowPass = context.createBiquadFilter();
lowPass.connect(context.destination);
lowPass.frequency.value = 500;
lowPass.Q.value = 0.5;
lowPass.frequency.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(200, now + 1);

oscillator.connect(lowPass);

oscillator.start(now);
oscillator.stop(now + 2);
```

edit: I just realized it does actually work in chrome. But I mainly use firefox, can I just not use webaudio yet?

Comment: Don't see how this would work in either Chrome or Firefox.  At the very least you need do `lowPass.connect(context.destination)`.  Then this should work with all browsers.

Comment: It should work in Firefox as well.  But maybe you need to add `lowPass.frequency.setValueAtTime(500, now)`, before you do the exponential ramp.

Answer (score 0):

```
The AudioParam interface has 2 modes:
A. Immediate
B. Automated
In mode A you simply set the value property of the parameter.
In mode B, if you want to 'ramp' from 500 to 200 you have
to use an automation event first to set the value to 500, eg:
frequency.setValueAtTime(500, 0)
A startTime parameter of zero applies the value immediately
according to the specs.
What you are trying is to intermingle both modes, but the latter
does not take the value of the first into account.
```